# Google Maps How do I get the current CameraLocation object?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

When I close my map or switch a different activity, the map calls the onSaveInstanseState(). I want to get the current camera position and LatLng so that when the user switches back to the map, they will be in the same location.

Thank you.

Comment: I think there is also the issue of saving the zoom level of the map when you switch activities.  Maybe you don't need to even save the camera position, I can't remember.

Comment: Google Maps have a getCameraPosition() method. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Maps have a getCameraPosition() method.

To get the latLang, you simple have to get the camera position then get the target. Such as:

```
LatLang latlang = googleMaps.getCameraPosition().target
```